# Can baby animals fit through a one-block high hole?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[Baby animals](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Baby_animals) are much smaller and cuter than their adult counterparts. Are piglets, calves, and lambs small enough to fit through a one-block high hole in a wall?

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated, see the second one.

Comment: @Timtech thanks for pointing that out. After testing it in creative mode, I accepted the new answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In previous versions of MineCraft, a baby animal (or villager) had the same hitbox as a parent (even though they *looked* smaller). But, in version 1.5 this was fixed so babies are smaller than their parents.

As has been pointed out, **pigs** and **chickens** are already only 1 block tall, so an even smaller baby animal makes no difference.

However, adult **cows**, **sheep**, and **villagers** are taller than one block, allowing them to be filtered from the babies who *can* fit through a 1 block gap.

Answer (score 18):

Upon further research, this attribute appears to be the same as the parent.

**Pigs**, both big and small, **can**.

[image]

Adult **sheep cannot**.

[image]

Little **sheep** also **cannot**.  Try as I might, I could *not* get this little guy to pass under, although he looks short enough.

[image]

**Cows cannot.**  I don't think I need to test the adult cows, but I got the same story with the calf as with the baby sheep.

[image]

I wasn't fast enough to screencap the chickens, so just trust me when I say, **chickens** are *definitely* small enough.

Comment: Come to think of it, can't normal pigs?

Comment: @Ullallulloo After a bit more testing, yes they can.

Comment: Huh I thought the larger ones couldn't.

Comment: @Arkive Me too.  I think certain larger ones like cows and sheep can't.

Comment: @John If you add research with cows and/or sheep, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Alright. I'll see what I can do. Give me a day or two.

Comment: @Arkive Additional research added.

Answer (score 0):

Use snow (the ones like carpets).

I made a pig farm and was trying to separate the young and adults. I built a slab and used snow, only the babies were able to pass through, however I am not too sure about other animals.

Answer (score -3):

I have come to the conclusion that sheep definitely can. So all babies should be able too.

Comment: diffidently can?

Comment: Adult sheep can't.